# Break a list of dictionaries (json)

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a following json [data](https://www.jezdectvi.org/cjf-breeders/data/horse-pedigree-data/0c827a0a-9489-4580-a373-d20c5e27859f/2020/).

The structure of object 'parents' is:

```
parents:[{
           "efficiency_d": null,
           "efficiency_c": null, 
           "efficiency_a": null, 
           "color": null,  
           "internal_number_uek": null, 
           "name_uek": "Tixaquir", 
           "race": "LUSITANO", 
           "parents": [{
                        ...same as above ...,
                        "parents" : [{},{}]
                       },
                       {
                        ...same as above ...,
                        "parents" : [{},{]]
                       }]

         },
         {
           "efficiency_d": null,
           "efficiency_c": null, 
           "efficiency_a": null, 
           "color": null,  
           "internal_number_uek": null, 
           "name_uek": "Tixaquir", 
           "race": "LUSITANO", 
           "parents": [{},{}]
         }]
```

I would like to break each list 'parents' to objects as

```
sire = js['parents'][0]
dam = js['parents'][1]
```

But for all levels (indents) of the item 'parents'.
so the object would look like:

```
'sire' : {
           "efficiency_d": null,
           "efficiency_c": null, 
           "efficiency_a": null, 
           "color": null,  
           "internal_number_uek": null, 
           "name_uek": "Tixaquir", 
           "race": "LUSITANO", 
           "sire":{
                   ...same as above ...,
                   "sire" :{},
                   "dam"  :{}
                   },
            "dam" :{
                   ...same as above...,
                   "sire" :{},
                   "dam"  :{}
                    }

         },
'dam':  {
           "efficiency_d": null,
           "efficiency_c": null, 
           "efficiency_a": null, 
           "color": null,  
           "internal_number_uek": null, 
           "name_uek": "Tixaquir", 
           "race": "LUSITANO", 
           "sire": {},
           "dam" : {}
         }
```

The problem I am struggling with is a chained item 'parents'. I tried some iterations over the python dictionary returned from json.loads(js.decode("utf-8")) but always failed.
I am using python 3.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly: you want to replace each `'parents':[...]` with `{'sire':..., 'dam':...}` structure.

```
import json


txt = '''{"efficiency_d": "T", "efficiency_c": null, "efficiency_a": null, "color": "Ryz.", "descendants_top_efficiency": {"a": null, "s": null, "c": null, "d": null}, "descendants": [{"efficiency_d": null, "efficiency_c": null, "efficiency_a": null, "color": "Ryz.", "internal_number_uek": null, "name_uek": "Nordico D' Pardinhos", "race": "LUSITANO", "efficiency_s": null, "licence": null, "id": "cd93f4a4-e48b-4bcc-a8bb-a9901f11f2cf", "birth_year": 2017}, {"efficiency_d": null, "efficiency_c": null, "efficiency_a": null, "color": "B\u011bl.", "internal_number_uek": null, "name_uek": "Lidador d'Pardinhos", "race": "LUSITANO", "efficiency_s": null, "licence": null, "id": "b1b24446-7d6d-486c-ab46-bff6d77ed1dc", "birth_year": 2015}, {"efficiency_d": null, "efficiency_c": null, "efficiency_a": null, "color": "B\u011bl.", "internal_number_uek": null, "name_uek": "Jade Dos Pardinhos", "race": "LUSITANO", "efficiency_s": null, "licence": null, "id": "a1d1ff36-8666-4fbf-8cd6-79eb427eb2c7", "birth_year": 2014}, {"efficiency_d": null, "efficiency_c": null, "efficiency_a": null, "color": "Ryz.", "internal_number_uek": null, "name_uek": "Jandaia D'Pardinhos", "race": "LUSITANO", "efficiency_s": null, "licence": null, "id": "4c19ebb2-6270-4a24-b322-ec035ae136cd", "birth_year": 2014}], "internal_number_uek": null, "name_uek": "Destino Pardinhos", "race": "LUSITANO", "parents": [{"efficiency_d": null, "efficiency_c": null, "efficiency_a": null, "color": null, "internal_number_uek": null, "name_uek": "Tixaquir", "race": "LUSITANO", "parents": [{"efficiency_d": null, "efficiency_c": null, "efficiency_a": null, "color": null, "internal_number_uek": null, "name_uek": "Xaquiro", "race": null, "parents": [{"parents": [{"parents": [{}, {}]}, {"parents": [{}, {}]}]}, {"parents": [{"parents": [{}, {}]}, {"parents": [{}, {}]}]}], "efficiency_s": null, "licence": null, "id": null, "birth_year": null}, {"efficiency_d": null, "efficiency_c": null, "efficiency_a": null, "color": null, "internal_number_uek": null, "name_uek": "Oxigenada", "race": null, "parents": [{"parents": [{"parents": [{}, {}]}, {"parents": [{}, {}]}]}, {"parents": [{"parents": [{}, {}]}, {"parents": [{}, {}]}]}], "efficiency_s": null, "licence": null, "id": null, "birth_year": null}], "efficiency_s": null, "licence": null, "id": "f62937b0-1af5-49aa-b65e-ec1b2849e529", "birth_year": 2000}, {"efficiency_d": null, "efficiency_c": null, "efficiency_a": null, "color": null, "internal_number_uek": null, "name_uek": "Unanime", "race": "LUSITANO", "parents": [{"efficiency_d": null, "efficiency_c": null, "efficiency_a": null, "color": null, "internal_number_uek": null, "name_uek": "Navegante", "race": null, "parents": [{"parents": [{"parents": [{}, {}]}, {"parents": [{}, {}]}]}, {"parents": [{"parents": [{}, {}]}, {"parents": [{}, {}]}]}], "efficiency_s": null, "licence": null, "id": null, "birth_year": null}, {"efficiency_d": null, "efficiency_c": null, "efficiency_a": null, "color": null, "internal_number_uek": null, "name_uek": "Piza", "race": null, "parents": [{"parents": [{"parents": [{}, {}]}, {"parents": [{}, {}]}]}, {"parents": [{"parents": [{}, {}]}, {"parents": [{}, {}]}]}], "efficiency_s": null, "licence": null, "id": null, "birth_year": null}], "efficiency_s": null, "licence": null, "id": "b13858af-2b60-4319-bd38-928912d6871a", "birth_year": 2001}], "efficiency_s": null, "licence": "KJ00TU", "id": "0c827a0a-9489-4580-a373-d20c5e27859f", "birth_year": 2008}'''
data = json.loads(txt)

def traverse(d):
    if 'parents' in d:
        sire, dam = d['parents']
        del d['parents']
        if sire:
            d['sire'] = sire
            traverse(sire)
        if dam:
            d['dam'] = dam
            traverse(dam)

traverse(data)
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "efficiency_d": "T",
    "efficiency_c": null,
    "efficiency_a": null,
    "color": "Ryz.",
    "descendants_top_efficiency": {
        "a": null,
        "s": null,
        "c": null,
        "d": null
    },
    "descendants": [
        {
            "efficiency_d": null,
            "efficiency_c": null,
            "efficiency_a": null,
            "color": "Ryz.",
            "internal_number_uek": null,
            "name_uek": "Nordico D' Pardinhos",
            "race": "LUSITANO",
            "efficiency_s": null,
            "licence": null,
            "id": "cd93f4a4-e48b-4bcc-a8bb-a9901f11f2cf",
            "birth_year": 2017
        },
        {
            "efficiency_d": null,
            "efficiency_c": null,
            "efficiency_a": null,
            "color": "B\u011bl.",
            "internal_number_uek": null,
            "name_uek": "Lidador d'Pardinhos",
            "race": "LUSITANO",
            "efficiency_s": null,
            "licence": null,
            "id": "b1b24446-7d6d-486c-ab46-bff6d77ed1dc",
            "birth_year": 2015
        },
        {
            "efficiency_d": null,
            "efficiency_c": null,
            "efficiency_a": null,
            "color": "B\u011bl.",
            "internal_number_uek": null,
            "name_uek": "Jade Dos Pardinhos",
            "race": "LUSITANO",
            "efficiency_s": null,
            "licence": null,
            "id": "a1d1ff36-8666-4fbf-8cd6-79eb427eb2c7",
            "birth_year": 2014
        },
        {
            "efficiency_d": null,
            "efficiency_c": null,
            "efficiency_a": null,
            "color": "Ryz.",
            "internal_number_uek": null,
            "name_uek": "Jandaia D'Pardinhos",
            "race": "LUSITANO",
            "efficiency_s": null,
            "licence": null,
            "id": "4c19ebb2-6270-4a24-b322-ec035ae136cd",
            "birth_year": 2014
        }
    ],
    "internal_number_uek": null,
    "name_uek": "Destino Pardinhos",
    "race": "LUSITANO",
    "efficiency_s": null,
    "licence": "KJ00TU",
    "id": "0c827a0a-9489-4580-a373-d20c5e27859f",
    "birth_year": 2008,
    "sire": {
        "efficiency_d": null,
        "efficiency_c": null,
        "efficiency_a": null,
        "color": null,
        "internal_number_uek": null,
        "name_uek": "Tixaquir",
        "race": "LUSITANO",
        "efficiency_s": null,
        "licence": null,
        "id": "f62937b0-1af5-49aa-b65e-ec1b2849e529",
        "birth_year": 2000,
        "sire": {
            "efficiency_d": null,
            "efficiency_c": null,
            "efficiency_a": null,
            "color": null,
            "internal_number_uek": null,
            "name_uek": "Xaquiro",
            "race": null,
            "efficiency_s": null,
            "licence": null,
            "id": null,
            "birth_year": null,
            "sire": {
                "sire": {},
                "dam": {}
            },
            "dam": {
                "sire": {},
                "dam": {}
            }
        },
        "dam": {
            "efficiency_d": null,
            "efficiency_c": null,
            "efficiency_a": null,
            "color": null,
            "internal_number_uek": null,
            "name_uek": "Oxigenada",
            "race": null,
            "efficiency_s": null,
            "licence": null,
            "id": null,
            "birth_year": null,
            "sire": {
                "sire": {},
                "dam": {}
            },
            "dam": {
                "sire": {},
                "dam": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "dam": {
        "efficiency_d": null,
        "efficiency_c": null,
        "efficiency_a": null,
        "color": null,
        "internal_number_uek": null,
        "name_uek": "Unanime",
        "race": "LUSITANO",
        "efficiency_s": null,
        "licence": null,
        "id": "b13858af-2b60-4319-bd38-928912d6871a",
        "birth_year": 2001,
        "sire": {
            "efficiency_d": null,
            "efficiency_c": null,
            "efficiency_a": null,
            "color": null,
            "internal_number_uek": null,
            "name_uek": "Navegante",
            "race": null,
            "efficiency_s": null,
            "licence": null,
            "id": null,
            "birth_year": null,
            "sire": {
                "sire": {},
                "dam": {}
            },
            "dam": {
                "sire": {},
                "dam": {}
            }
        },
        "dam": {
            "efficiency_d": null,
            "efficiency_c": null,
            "efficiency_a": null,
            "color": null,
            "internal_number_uek": null,
            "name_uek": "Piza",
            "race": null,
            "efficiency_s": null,
            "licence": null,
            "id": null,
            "birth_year": null,
            "sire": {
                "sire": {},
                "dam": {}
            },
            "dam": {
                "sire": {},
                "dam": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```